# jQuery debounce, way to pass the element along to the function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

**HTML**

```
<input class="list_item_title mini" name="list_item[title]" size="30" type="text" value="What happens when a user creates a new item?">
```

**JS:**

```
function text_2(e) {
    console.log(e.val());
};

$(function() {
    $('input.list_item_title').keyup( $.debounce( 250, text_2 ) );
});
```

e.val() currently doesn't work. how can I pass the input along so I can get the value?

Thanks

Comment: Is it this one http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/ ?

Comment: yea that's the one! http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? And what are you actually trying to do? "The input"? "The value"? Why so vague? Try writing some sentences in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` is a reference to the [**event object** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), not the `input` element.

You can get a reference to the `input` element using [`event.currentTarget` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).

After the having a look at the source code, you should also be able to access the element with `this` (like in any other event handler), so the following should work:

```
function text_2(e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($(e.target).val());
```

Comment: In this case `target` indeed refers to the element the handler was bound to. But in general, it could be that the event originated  at some descendant. `currentTarget` would be safer to use (but as it turns out, `this` is fine too).